# How to scale my app on nginx metrics without prometheus?

Tags: kubernetes, horizontalpodautoscaler

I want to scale my application based on custom metrics (RPS or active connections in this cases). Without having to set up prometheus or use any external service. I can expose this API from my web app. What are my options?

Comment: I suggest using Prometheus or other similar *reliable* tools designed for this purpose.
As a workaround, you can try to use a script to continuously monitor your nginx metrics, and when these metrics are above/under some limits you can run `kubectl scale` commands from this script.

Comment: yeah. ended up using prometheus with keda to get it done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Monitoring different types of metrics (e.g. custom metrics) on most Kubernetes clusters is the foundation that leads to more stable and reliable systems/applications/workloads. As discussed in the comments section, to monitor custom metrics, it is recommended to use  tools designed for this purpose rather than inventing a workaround. I'm glad that in this case the final decision was to use [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/) and [KEDA](https://keda.sh/) to properly scale the web application.

I would like to briefly show other community members who are struggling with similar considerations how KEDA works.

---

To use Prometheus as a scaler for Keda, we need to install and configure Prometheus.
There are many different ways to install Prometheus and you should choose the one that suits your needs.

I've installed the [kube-prometheus stack](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack#kube-prometheus-stack) with Helm:
**NOTE:** I allowed Prometheus to discover all `PodMonitors`/`ServiceMonitors` within its namespace, without applying label filtering by setting the `prometheus.prometheusSpec.podMonitorSelectorNilUsesHelmValues` and `prometheus.prometheusSpec.serviceMonitorSelectorNilUsesHelmValues` values to `false`.

```
$ helm repo add prometheus-community https://prometheus-community.github.io/helm-charts
$ helm repo update
$ helm install prom-1 prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack --set prometheus.prometheusSpec.podMonitorSelectorNilUsesHelmValues=false --set prometheus.prometheusSpec.serviceMonitorSelectorNilUsesHelmValues=false

$ kubectl get pods
NAME                                                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
alertmanager-prom-1-kube-prometheus-sta-alertmanager-0   2/2     Running   0          2m29s
prom-1-grafana-865d4c8876-8zdhm                          3/3     Running   0          2m34s
prom-1-kube-prometheus-sta-operator-6b5d5d8df5-scdjb     1/1     Running   0          2m34s
prom-1-kube-state-metrics-74b4bb7857-grbw9               1/1     Running   0          2m34s
prom-1-prometheus-node-exporter-2v2s6                    1/1     Running   0          2m34s
prom-1-prometheus-node-exporter-4vc9k                    1/1     Running   0          2m34s
prom-1-prometheus-node-exporter-7jchl                    1/1     Running   0          2m35s
prometheus-prom-1-kube-prometheus-sta-prometheus-0       2/2     Running   0          2m28s
```

Then we can deploy an application that will be monitored by Prometheus. I've created a simple application that exposes some metrics (such as `nginx_vts_server_requests_total`) on the `/status/format/prometheus` path:

```
$ cat app-1.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app-1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app-1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: app-1
        image: mattjcontainerregistry/nginx-vts:v1.0
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 50m
          requests:
            cpu: 50m
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: http
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app-1
  labels:
    app: app-1
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    name: http
  selector:
    app: app-1
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Next, create a [ServiceMonitor](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/main/Documentation/user-guides/getting-started.md#related-resources) that describes how to monitor our `app-1` application:

```
$ cat servicemonitor.yaml
kind: ServiceMonitor
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
metadata:
  name: app-1
  labels:
    app: app-1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app-1
  endpoints:
  - interval: 15s
    path: "/status/format/prometheus"
    port: http
```

After waiting some time, let's check the `app-1` logs to make sure that it is scrapped correctly:

```
$ kubectl get pods | grep app-1
app-1-5986d56f7f-2plj5                                   1/1     Running   0          35s

$ kubectl logs -f app-1-5986d56f7f-2plj5
10.44.1.6 - - [07/Feb/2022:16:31:11 +0000] "GET /status/format/prometheus HTTP/1.1" 200 2742 "-" "Prometheus/2.33.1" "-"
10.44.1.6 - - [07/Feb/2022:16:31:26 +0000] "GET /status/format/prometheus HTTP/1.1" 200 3762 "-" "Prometheus/2.33.1" "-"
10.44.1.6 - - [07/Feb/2022:16:31:41 +0000] "GET /status/format/prometheus HTTP/1.1" 200 3762 "-" "Prometheus/2.33.1" "-"
```

Now it's time to deploy KEDA. There are a few approaches to deploy KEDA runtime as described in the [KEDA documentation](https://keda.sh/docs/2.6/deploy/).
I chose to install KEDA with Helm because it's very simple :-)

```
$ helm repo add kedacore https://kedacore.github.io/charts
$ helm repo update
$ kubectl create namespace keda
$ helm install keda kedacore/keda --namespace keda
```

The last thing we need to create is a [`ScaledObject`](https://keda.sh/docs/1.4/concepts/scaling-deployments/#scaledobject-spec) which is used to define how KEDA should scale our application and what the triggers are. In the example below, I used the `nginx_vts_server_requests_total` metric.
**NOTE:** For more information on the prometheus trigger, see the [Trigger Specification](https://keda.sh/docs/2.6/scalers/prometheus/) documentation.

```
$ cat scaled-object.yaml
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledObject
metadata:
  name: scaled-app-1
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: app-1
  pollingInterval: 30                               
  cooldownPeriod:  120                              
  minReplicaCount: 1                                
  maxReplicaCount: 5                               
  advanced:                                         
    restoreToOriginalReplicaCount: false            
    horizontalPodAutoscalerConfig:                  
      behavior:                                     
        scaleDown:
          stabilizationWindowSeconds: 300
          policies:
          - type: Percent
            value: 100
            periodSeconds: 15
  triggers:
  - type: prometheus
    metadata:
      serverAddress: http://prom-1-kube-prometheus-sta-prometheus.default.svc:9090
      metricName: nginx_vts_server_requests_total
      query: sum(rate(nginx_vts_server_requests_total{code="2xx", service="app-1"}[2m])) # Note: query must return a vector/scalar single element response
      threshold: '10'
  
$ kubectl apply -f scaled-object.yaml
scaledobject.keda.sh/scaled-app-1 created
```

Finally, we can check if the `app-1` application scales correctly based on the number of requests:

```
$ for a in $(seq 1 10000); do curl <PUBLIC_IP_APP_1> 1>/dev/null 2>&1; done

$ kubectl get hpa -w
NAME                    REFERENCE          TARGETS          MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   
keda-hpa-scaled-app-1   Deployment/app-1   0/10 (avg)        1         5         1           
keda-hpa-scaled-app-1   Deployment/app-1   15/10 (avg)       1         5         2         
keda-hpa-scaled-app-1   Deployment/app-1   12334m/10 (avg)   1         5         3       
keda-hpa-scaled-app-1   Deployment/app-1   13250m/10 (avg)   1         5         4      
keda-hpa-scaled-app-1   Deployment/app-1   12600m/10 (avg)   1         5         5          

$ kubectl get pods | grep app-1
app-1-5986d56f7f-2plj5                                   1/1     Running   0          36m
app-1-5986d56f7f-5nrqd                                   1/1     Running   0          77s
app-1-5986d56f7f-78jw8                                   1/1     Running   0          94s
app-1-5986d56f7f-bl859                                   1/1     Running   0          62s
app-1-5986d56f7f-xlfp6                                   1/1     Running   0          45s
```

As you can see above, our application has been correctly scaled to 5 replicas.